# I want to make validations using Jquery validate plugin but it does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to make validations using Jquery validate in my asp .net view but the plugin  does not work

my html code :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Organization",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype="multipart/form-data", id = "myform" })) {
  <input  type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </form>
}
```

scripts:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,

            }
        }
    });

});
     });
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are using `$('#myform').isValid()`

Comment: i still not make it

Comment: Your Razor is wrong. Why don't you view the rendered output and see if its **valid markup** for your `form` block. Do you have a submit button? End of day, it's still a standard `form` that needs to be `submit`ted somehow.